# Can for future possibility

Tags: word-order, modality

I'm doing a research on English modality (for reference I'm using F.R. Palmer's book "Modality and the English Modals").

In the book the author distinguishes between the three kinds of modality:

Epistemic modality (for possibility)

Deontic (for permission and obligation)

Dynamic (subject oriented "modality" i.e. objective potential)

To test the practical application of the theoretical points given in this book, I turn to native speakers' aid, but the issue is that everyone appears to have their own interpretations of modality in what seems to be the same context (some might understand a modal to be deontic (e.g. you have my permission to do that), while others understand it as dynamic (there is an objective possibility to do that).

To have a better understanding of what I mean, please, take a look at my thread on wordreference.com (particularly at the post #8, where I give a link to yet another one of my posts).

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/can-will-be-able-to.3627055/

Only few people accepted the use of "can" there, but here (#1, Ex. 4) a similar example was validated:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/can-or-be-able-to-in-the-future.3626301/#post-1847635

There seems to be some misconception at play. This might be due to the fact that when we acquire language as children, we absorb it intuitively with no instructions. The language doesn't come in a package together with a user guide like a table from IKEA or some exhaustive grammar book explaining how our mind generates grammar. There's nothing to language but the language, so oftentimes we have to base our inferences on intuition. My objective here is to understand whether "can" is indeed not used to denote objective future possiby or is it just that the native speakers preceive "can" in my examples to be something else (e.g. permission or epistemic possibility).

Could you, please, check if my assumptions about the meaning of "can" in the following sentences are correct. If they are not, how would you interpret them?

Ex.1

A: What is this bank good for?! We all are jobless!

B: When Barclays opens a branch in our town, you [can / will be able to] apply for a job there ("B" merely states a fact about future possibility; "to be able to" is more naural here).

Ex.2

A: I need to find a job.

B: When Barclays opens a branch in our town, you can apply for a job there ("B" suggests a solution; in such situations "can" looks better. In the book this use of "can" is titled as "implication").

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/can_1) includes: << **can** _modal_ ... There is no future tense [inflected form] of _can_, but _will be able to_ is used for saying that someone will have the ability to do something or that something will be possible in the future, especially after a long time: ... _She’ll be able to walk soon. ... 
A hundred years from now people will be able to visit Mars._ 
'Can' is usually used when planning or deciding about the near future:
_We can go shopping tomorrow._ >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have [opened a 'Can' of worms](http://mentalfloss.com/article/31039/how-did-term-open-can-worms-originate) here! (Sorry for the idiomatic reference).  To answer your edit, "To be able to..." is used in more formal environments, whereas "Can", tends to be the more informal alternative.  For example, I would use:

If doctor to patient: "Are you able to bend your knees?"

If mother to child (or perhaps nurse to patient): "Can you bend you knees for me?"

[Can is a very complicated subject.](https://www.lingokids.com/english-for-kids/verb-can)

If Barclays [or any other bank for that matter] opens a branch "you can apply for a job there [*if you want to... / you have the ability*]  The writer is suggesting that, in my opinion, you have the ability (permissive in this sense).

It could also be used informally / [scoffingly](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scoffingly) in the negative: "*You can apply for a job there if you want to!*... With the subtext: But I would not [because its a terrible job!]"

From an information presentation style, I would normally put the pre-condition [When Barclays, open a branch] first, because the action [applying for the job] is conditional on this having happened first.  If Barclays change their mind and don't open the branch, THEN you may not want, or be able to apply for a job elsewhere - at another branch.  Therefore the *permission* is not required.

Equally, "If Barclays opens a branch in your town" - albeit highly unlikely in the present economic climate - it is also possible that you cannot [or can't] apply for a job there [*because they are fully staffed / you are not qualified / you are only 6-years old...*]

Comment: This usage has nothing to do with "giving permission".

Comment: Where is your evidence?

Comment: can: /kan,kən/
verb
1.
be able to.
"they can run fast"
2.
be permitted to.
"you can use the phone if you want to"

Comment: Cascabel, this is exactly the point! The underlying meaning of "can" in examples such as this always causes disagreement between the native speakers - some understand it to mean possibility, some - permission while others don't accept the use of "can" in this context at all.

Comment: Most native speakers I know and have known (UK) would find  'When Barclays open a branch in our town, you can apply for a job there' used conversationally to convey **either** natural (ie epistemic) possibility ('will be able to')  _or_ permission (ie the _deontic_ usage, 'are allowed to') totally acceptable.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin Ashworth!:) I thought "can" was used to express neutral possibility which is a subtype of dynamic modality, whereas epistemic modality is only concerned with probability. Dynamic (neutral possibility): it can go either way (we know this for a fact);  epistemic (probability): it might be dangerous (or might not).

Comment: Look at the definitions [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) gives. I'd take dynamic modality here (''When Barclays open a branch in our town, you _can_ apply for a job there! Yes, you **can**! I know you've got it in you! _You can do it!_") as needing real emphasis. A third possible reading, but unlikely, and needing context to identify.

Comment: @VsevolodIV I can only see this particular usage (like in your example) as either epistemic or neutral. I do not understand how a person who has no position of authority at the bank can extend permission (deontic), unless possibly it is a parent talking to their kid. But for that we would need some more context.

Comment: 'Can' in this sense is permissive in that the speaker is expressing a personal opinion of the possibilities, or likelyhood of success, as opposed to a firm job offer.  Can is a very complex word that can [pardon me] be used in many different ways.  This site offer a good explanation:  https://www.lingokids.com/english-for-kids/verb-can

Comment: One of the peculiarities of the verb “can” is that it doesn’t have a future form. If a person wants to express any of the uses of this verb in the future, then that person has to use the verb “be able to”. This verb maintains the meaning, but it makes possible for the speaker to talk in future form or to make some more complex tenses since it can be combined with the future form “will”, and since it contains the verb “to be” which can be conjugated in all its forms.

Comment: @Cascabel 'You are allowed to' doesn't require that the speaker is _giving_ permission; they could be saying that they see no reason that the person is disqualified from the course of action. As I have always read it, 'deontic modality' 'has to do with conformation to a perceived set of moral laws (as opposed to laws of nature)  /  expectations', so an interpretation of such rules rather than solely a laying down of them is included. "Drivers may do seventy along that stretch of road [,if I remember rightly]."

Comment: @NeilB that is what was taught, but the author suggests that "can" and "be able to" are not interchangeable: 1) "be able to" is not use to mean implication (we can send it to you, if you wish) 2) "..."be able to" seems to have some sense of ability (in a fairly wide sense) and to be more subject orient than "can"..." (But are there degrees of subject orientation? I thought the proposition could be either subject oriented or not). 3) "be able to" is more formal than "can"...

Comment: 4) "be able to" suggests the idea "I can and I do": by bulk buying in specific items, Lasky's [are able to / can] cut prices on packages by as much as 30 percent. The author holds it that "be able to" indicates "that's what we normally do" while "can" - "there's a future possibility".

Comment: He also adds the following: "...However, it must not be assumed that "be able to" supplies the missing forms of "can"..."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Explained that way...I guess I can accept it. I just could not see it the way it was put in the answer.

Comment: Every day's a school day...

Comment: Thank you for your edit...this looks better now.